# Angular 4: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access and print the particular data in console window from the server. For some reason it throws an error on like

**Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1**

and the issue causes of `get<ProductData>`  Can you please correct me what's wrong?

**Note:** If I access complete data without typed response it works fine.

```
interface ProductData {
  userId: string;
  id: number;
  title: string;    
} 


private productUrl:string = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";

  ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get<ProductData>(this.productUrl).subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data.userId);
        })

}
```

Comment: Are you using `Http` or `HttpClient` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using http

Comment: use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`

Comment: thank you. It is working great.

Comment: This question helped me. I didn't know there was a distinction between Http and HttpClient.

Answer (score 3):

HttpClient has generic methods that can be used to provide response type. Http doesn't.

The error means that  generic parameter wasn't expected, and http isn't an instance of HttpClient; likely an instance of Http.

If the application uses Angular 4.3 or higher, Http should be replaced with HttpClient. In case Http should be used, a response should be transformed, this is one of few differences between HttpClient and Http:

```
return this.http.get(uri, { params })
.map(res => <ProductData[]>res.json());
```

Details: https://angular.io/guide/http